# using papa parse function to keep polling a file which is getting updated in background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, papaparse

I am completely new to javascript, so i am clueless on callback and other stuffs, i could manage a working setup when a file is there with data using jquery

```
$.get('./File.csv', function (csvString) {
            var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true, skipEmptyLines: true }).data;
            console.log(data)
```

This works fine, but now my problem is i need to poll the file and perform tasks from new rows added into, so i changed this jquery into a function to use papa parse, and used `setInterval` to keep polling the file

This is how it looks like now.

```
function_A(i,a,b,c) {
            var csvString = "./File.csv"
            var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true, skipEmptyLines: true }).data;
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data.length)
            var i = i;
            var a = a;
            var b = b;
            var c = c;
            var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                console.log(data[i]);
                console.log("Value of i: " + i)
                var row = data[i];
                if (condition) {
                    a++;
                } else if (condition) {
                    b++;
                } else if (condition) {
                    c++;
                } else {
                    pass
                }
                i++;
                function_B(a,b,c);
                function_C(a,b,c);
                console.log("Value of i after end of iteration: " + i)
                console.log("a: " + a + " b: " + b + " c: " + c)
                if (i == data.length) {
                    console.log("I am in if loop")
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 2000);
            return { i, a, b, c };
        }

function_B(){}
function_C(){}

var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            var csvString = "./File.csv"
            var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true, skipEmptyLines: true }).data;
            console.log("No Data to load" + data)
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Starting the main function")
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    let retured_data = function_A(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    let i = retured_data.i;
                    let a = retured_data.a;
                    let b = retured_data.b;
                    let c = retured_data.c;
                    var interval_next = window.setInterval(function () {
                        i++
                        let retured_data = function_A(i, a, b, c);
                        let i = retured_data.i;
                        let a = retured_data.a;
                        let b = retured_data.b;
                        let c = retured_data.c;
                        if (data.length == 191) {
                            console.log("Complete Data Loaded")
                            clearInterval(interval_next);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
}, 2000);
```

I know it's a poor code, i am not trying to be clean, just want this to work, please help. The problem is in the main function papa parse doesn't return anything for rest of the piece to work, i tried changing code using await and promise and call back. If anyone can help me with fixing below code would appreciate

Comment: You need to read the file every 3000ms since the data is changing over time ?

Comment: why are you clearing and setting interval? seems like once the data length is 191, you'll stop re-reading the file

Comment: @Bravo yes file will be updated with 191 rows only, so after that polling can stop

Comment: @CesarePolonara Yes data is changing by a backend code which keeps on updating the file with new rows, in fact one of the other possible issue is while your reading the file it is getting changed at the same time, but even if that's the case the papa parse should take point in time content of the file isn't it?

Comment: Why don't you send a stream from BE and just attach a stream reader through a fetch ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: @CesarePolonara something like as `fs` now that's a different issue, this code is a piece of leaflet javascipt code where i am polling the file and putting the locations in leaflet map, when i use `fs` if you mean BE as same it doesn't work, it starts giving me error on pieces which were working before.

Comment: @CesarePolonara As i said, i am just customising code from here and there which is a mess i know, so if you could share a working example here, then i can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario can be managed in different ways.
 If you have control over BE, with a `node.js` BE you can attach a readable stream to the response body which is then read step by step from the client. This is a pretty powerful approach since the browser APIs now let you directly read from readabe streams. If you can't do that and you have a backend written in other languages, you could start a web socket connection, and let the server notify the client every time the `.csv` file has changed and then send the updated version. 
As last *( but worst )* resource, you can poll from client, I don't get specifically into how you are trying to manipulate the data you receive, but this would be a basic idea of how to handle this:

```js
const getURL = idx => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${idx}`
let counter = 0 // Just to show data updated in time
let interval;

const getData = async() => {
  counter++
  try {
    const res = await fetch(getURL(counter))
    const data = await res.json() // use .text() since it's a csv file
    //use data
    result.innerText += `Fetch number: ${counter}\n`
    result.innerText += data.title + "\n"
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}



btn.onclick = () => interval = setInterval(getData, 3000)
stp.onclick = () => clearInterval(interval)
reset.onclick = () => {
  clearInterval(interval)
  result.innerText = ""
  counter = 0
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get data</button>
<button id="stp">Stop fetch</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div id="result">
  <div>
```

*I concat the results of the fetch to simulate a file integration received from BE*, in your case it would be even simplier since you only have to read the data as is, just make sure to parse it with `.text()` method and not `.json()` method, since it's a `.csv` file.

Comment: Thanks @Cesare, I tried fetch and seems to be working, However it runs for the very first load and doesn't iterate for the update data.

Comment: I will ask another question on how to fix that piece.